# How to apply feedforward correction to a simple three-stage amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, feedforward

I think I understand the principle of the feedforward error correction, but I have problems with the practice.

Having a simplified structure of a three-stage amplifier made with transistors, how a feedforward error correction is implemented, for example, on the second stage?

[image]

Also, is possible to use either feedback and feedforward technique together?

Comment: What do you mean by  "feedforward" and why would you want to use it on a conventional 3 stage amplifier?

Comment: https://hifisonix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Stochino-ff1.pdf

Comment: As it currently stands, it's unclear what the problem is you're trying to solve. Until you clarify, I don't believe anyone can really help you. user350400 provided a good link showing how a feed-forward error correction can be done. You wouldn't do it on a single stage of an amplifier though, and it required a completely separate amplifier to perform the correction.

Comment: Or asked more concisely, what error are you trying to remove? The standard use case of an op-amp is to have crazy high gain so that one can use that to remove most of the error between the inputs using negative feedback. Obviously there's downsides to that (like phase delay and reduction of gain-bandwidth product).

Comment: @horta I want to reduce distortion using a feedfoward error correction for pure sake of knowledge, because literature is very very little on the subject. I asked a very generic question because I understand the principle, but not the implementation, I don't even know if can be applied to a single stage or must be applied to the entire amplifier. I know for sure that can be applied to standard amplifiers (like the simplified example above), but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

When I look on your schematic the main source of disturbance are current sources and voltage amp.
Since the input stage is paired and also considering perfectly matched should be pretty stable.
Also if the output stage is well diode compensated and not much overdriven by the load should be also ok.

To make a good voltage amp you have two choices. Avoiding the beta dependency design or compensate beta with some another temperature dependent device (ntc, diodes).

Comment: As I said, the schematic is a simplified version of a three-stage amplifier, so it's obvious that it needs a lot of adjustments and improvements. The question is about how to apply a feedforward correction to it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest example of feed forward is the difference between Class B amp (your third stage) and a class AB amp. Because two transistors in the push-pull structure causes both high and low side transistors to shut off slightly away from the cross-over point a dead-zone is created. This is a form of distortion. To avoid this, they simple add diodes or diode connected transistors to offset the Base-Emitter voltage or threshold voltage of mosfets. This biases each of the output transistors differently so that their shutoff voltages are closer together. This reduces the cross-over dead-zone. Further biasing resistors or current mirrors could be used to tune how much of this feed forward error correction is performed to minimize the dead-zone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes

Perhaps what you're struggling with is that electronic design is filled with feed-forward error correction, it's just not called that. It's called biasing (in this case).

The second stage of the amplifier you showed is probably a bad example to ask for forward-error-correction because it's a common-emitter amplifier which is simply a high gain stage. CE amps aren't necessarily after any specific linearity because the goal is high gain. The closest thing to forward error correction for CE amps is emitter degeneration. As the wiki states, it's not really negative feedback, and it is correcting distortion. According to the definition of feed forward, emitter degeneration isn't correcting the input, but rather the output so it's not really either negative or forward feedback.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter

The other possible improvement I'm aware of to reduce noise/distortion for a CE amp is to cascode it. Once again, this is a modification to adjust the output rather than the input to improve performance. It's not directly negative feedback and it's not exactly forward error correction (FEC) either.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode

In summary, I believe my first example is the best example of forward error correction in an amplifier. That matches with your 3rd stage. I don't believe the 2nd stage can really benefit from FEC though because of the design goals of the CE amp. Perhaps if you were looking for a really complex mechanism for FEC on a CE amp, you could use an op-amp to down-scale the input range to reduce the rail-to-rail requirements on the CE stage. That would increase the range and linearity of the CE amp's output.